# How do I get multiple rows for a node's data section in NetworkX

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, networkx

I have the following pandas data frame:

```
    Node      Col1  Col2  Col3
     1         A     B     C
     1         D     E     F
     1         G     H     I
     2         A     B     I
     2         G     E     F
```

I need to put each Node into a Graph (which I can do) but I need the data section to include all rows for each Column. Such that I can access each columns' data and retrieve the correct row.

I think I want a Dictionary where for Node 1: {Col1: [A, D, G], Col2: [B, E, H], Col3: [C, F, I]} but I know lists/dictionaries can be weird each row data would need to be accessed so if I want access Col1: D; I can also access Col2: E, and Col3: F.

In other words, the ordinal position of each list in the dictionary accesses the correct data.

I've done a groupby on the data frame such as:

```
    df.groupby('Node')['Col1'].apply(list)
```

will give me the list I want but am I guaranteed that each list will have the correct ordinal position of the data.

Is there a way to combine multiple dictionary values into a Node's data section and then access it?

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: It's going into a NetworkX graph so less concerned about output and really looking to find out what is happening in the network. But a node exists in multiple domains which is what I need to show.